# Chinese Remainder Theorem Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to write a function or functions in Haskell that can solve the Chinese Remainder Theorem. It needs to be created with the following definition:

```
crt :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> (Integer, Integer)
```

That the answer looks like

```
>crt [(2,7), (0,3), (1,5)]
(51, 105)
```

I think I have the overall idea, I just don't have the knowledge to write it. I know that the crt function must be recursive. I have created a helper function to split the list of tuples into a tuple of two lists:

```
crtSplit xs = (map fst xs, product(map snd xs))
```

Which, in this example, gives me:

```
([2,0,1],105)
```

I think what I need to do know is create a list for each of the elements in the first list. How would I begin to do this?

Answer (score 6):

Chinese remainder theorem has an [**algebraic solution**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#An_algebraic_approach), based on the fact that `x = r1 % m1` and `x = r2 % m2` can be reduced to one modular equation if `m1` and `m2` are [**coprime**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers).

To do so you need to know what [**modular inverse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) is and how it can efficiently be calculated using [**extended Euclidean algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

If you put these pieces together, you can solve Chinese remainder theorem with a [**right fold**](https://wiki.haskell.org/Fold):

```
crt :: (Integral a, Foldable t) => t (a, a) -> (a, a)
crt = foldr go (0, 1)
    where
    go (r1, m1) (r2, m2) = (r `mod` m, m)
        where
        r = r2 + m2 * (r1 - r2) * (m2 `inv` m1)
        m = m2 * m1

    -- Modular Inverse
    a `inv` m = let (_, i, _) = gcd a m in i `mod` m

    -- Extended Euclidean Algorithm
    gcd 0 b = (b, 0, 1)
    gcd a b = (g, t - (b `div` a) * s, s)
        where (g, s, t) = gcd (b `mod` a) a
```

then:

```
\> crt [(2,7), (0,3), (1,5)]
(51,105)
\> crt [(2,3), (3,4), (1,5)]  -- wiki example
(11,60)
```

Comment: I need to create a function with crt :: [(Integer, Integer)] -> (Integer, Integer) and I cannot import any outside data.

Answer (score 2):

Without going into algebra, you can also solve this with brute force.  Perhaps that's what you've been asked to do.

For your example, create a list for each mod independent of the other two (upper bound will be least common multiple of the mod, assuming they are co-prime as a precondition, product, i.e. 105).  These three list should have one common element which will satisfy all constraints.

```
m3 = [3,6,9,12,15,...,105]
m5 = [6,11,16,21,...,101]
m7 = [9,16,23,30,...,100]
```

you can use `Data.Set` to find the intersection of these lists.  Now, extend this logic to n number of terms using recursion or fold.

**Update**
Perhaps an easier approach is defining a filter to create a sequence with a fixed remainder for a modulus and repeatedly apply for the given pairs

```
Prelude> let rm (r,m) = filter (\x -> x `mod` m == r)
```

verify that it works,

```
Prelude> take 10 $ rm (1,5) [1..]                                               
[1,6,11,16,21,26,31,36,41,46]
```

now, for the given example use it repeatedly,

```
Prelude> take 3 $ rm (1,5) $ rm (0,3) $ rm (2,7) [1..]        
[51,156,261]
```

of course we just need the first element, change to head instead

```
Prelude> head $ rm (1,5) $ rm (0,3) $ rm (2,7) [1..]       
51
```

which we can generalize with fold

```
Prelude> head $ foldr rm [1..] [(1,5),(0,3),(2,7)]                            
51
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I need to do, I'm just stuck on how I execute this.

Comment: In order to solve, first you have to understand the problem.  I would suggest do this manually for a two elements first, perhaps three and then open `ghci` and interactively implement the steps either I suggested or any other way you come up with.  After then, try to implement the general case...